# Deserialization of nullable value with xsd.exe generated class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, xml-deserialization, xsd.exe

[Nullable value with xsd.exe generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420930/nullable-value-with-xsd-exe-genereated-class) answers why the generated class has a *Specified field and property, and how it's used for *serializing* an XML file, but how am I able to set this value during *deserialization*?

I have a generated class as defined below:

```cs
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.caiso.com/soa/2006-06-13/StandardOutput.xsd")]
public partial class EventLog {

    private System.DateTime creationTimeField;

    private bool creationTimeFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime creationTime {
        get {
            return this.creationTimeField;
        }
        set {
            this.creationTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool creationTimeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.creationTimeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.creationTimeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that `this.creationTimeFieldSpecified;` is not set in the setter of `creationTime`. How then, using xsd.exe, can I generate a class such that I can deserialize an XML, and check whether the value is supplied or not?

I am aware of other tools: xsd2code, wscfblue, XmlSchemaClassGenerator, etc; but with each release or update of Visual Studio, it's possible something changed, or the Add-In isn't supported. I would like to know if there is a way to generate the class such that deserialization can take advantage of these properties.

**Dislaimer**:

I do not have access to change the xsd, they can be updated at any time for any reason requiring a re-generation of the classes, and the resultant class can be many thousands of lines long, manual intervention is not-desired.