# Dictionary<string, List<ClassObj>> LINQ To XML Query

Tags: c#, xml

I try to put my XML File into a Dictionary with Generic List. How I can merge correct the query List to my dictionary with correct key? Instead of `.ToList()` `.ToDictionary` is not possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
  <cust ID="1" DeviceID="1" Name="Bob" Latitude="10" Longitude="58" Device="HW1.0"> </cust>
  <cust ID="2" DeviceID="2" Name="Jack" Latitude="28" Longitude="20" Device="HW2.2"> </cust>
</customers>

//XML attribute Name is Dict Key

public class Customers
{
    public int Longitude { get; set; }
    public int Latitude { get; set; }
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string Device { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    private static Dictionary<string, List<Customers>> ReadXmlToDict(string filename)
    {
        // Should be Key = Xml Attribute Name Value, List of class 
        Dictionary<string, List<Customers>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Customers>>();

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
        var querylist = (from row in xdoc.Descendants("cust")
                         select new Customers()
                         {
                             //Name = (string)row.Attribute("Name"),  // Wrong here should be the Dic key
                             DeviceID = (int)row.Attribute("DeviceID"), // list value
                             Longitude = (int)row.Attribute("Longitude"),  // list value
                             Latitude = (int)row.Attribute("Latitude"), // list value
                             Device = (string)row.Attribute("Device")  // list value
                         }).ToList();

        return null; // null for test To.List and not Dict
    }
```

Comment: Maybe something like this `(from row in xdoc.Descendants("cust")).ToDictionary(k => (string)row.Attribute("ID"), (v => select new Customers() { }).ToList());`?

Comment: Thank you,  but i have stil problems to make the linq query correct to Dictionary<String>,List<Customer>>. The syntax is still wrong, but your help gave me a idea. I will try.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would implement it, I think it accomplishes what you're looking for. You have a class called `Customers` and then want to store a list of those customers with a single key...I don't follow that logic.

I created a class called `Customer`, which houses the information for a singular customer. Since you're returning a `Dictionary<string, Customer>`, where the string is the unique attribute `Name` in the xml, there is no use case for the value of your dictionary being a `List<Customer>`. Perhaps if you have multiple customers under the same name, you would use this, but why not then make the key the (I assume) truly unique identifier, the `DeviceID`?

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    class Customer
    {
        public int DeviceID;
        public int Longitude;
        public int Latitude;
        public string Device;
    }
    class Program
    {

        private static Dictionary<string, Customer> ReadXmlToDictionary(string filename)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, Customer>();

            var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

            dict = doc.Descendants("cust")
                .ToDictionary(
                    row => (string)row.Attribute("Name"),
                    row => new Customer {
                        Device = (string)row.Attribute("Device"),
                        DeviceID = (int)row.Attribute("DeviceID"),
                        Latitude = (int)row.Attribute("Latitude"),
                        Longitude = (int)row.Attribute("Longitude")
                });

            return dict;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadXmlToDictionary(null);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image of results]

EDIT: Thought the performance related answer was interesting, so decided to try it out for this single level xml (using ID as the unique identifier). Here are the results:

```
1019 Descendants took 0.0030257 seconds.
1019 Elements took 0.0028348 seconds.
10000 Descendants took 0.0098942 seconds.
10000 Elements took 0.0101478 seconds.
100000 Descendants took 0.0873025 seconds.
100000 Elements took 0.1223577 seconds.
```

**EDIT**: 
After creating your xsd, and generating a class from it, you would then use it as such:

```
var parsed = XDocument.Parse(doc.ToString());

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xsds.customers));

var typedPayload = serializer.Deserialize(doc.Root.CreateReader());

var xmlAsClass = (TestConsole.Xsds.customers)typedPayload;

dict = xmlAsClass.cust
    .ToDictionary(
        row => (int)row.ID,
        row => new Customer {
            Device = row.Device,
            DeviceID = row.DeviceID,
            Latitude = row.Latitude,
            Longitude = row.Longitude,
            Name = row.Name
        });
```

Comment: You are totally right I need no List<customers>, because each customer should be unique by name. I had a missunderstanding not only in the correct syntax. Many thanks!

Comment: Related to my topic I have one more question. I really dont like hard coded values e.g. the Class for customers. Reuse is very low, a class based on Attributes would be nice, including generic xml Attribute names.

Comment: You can, and should, create an xsd. You could use this if you don't want to manually create your xsd: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output. Since some of these are nullable, I don't think you'll be able to use `xsd.exe` per the reasons here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610770/deserialization-of-nullable-value-with-xsd-exe-generated-class, so use xsd2code or wscfblue or some other tool to generate the class.

Comment: Nice Benchmark! XML Schema is understandible and I have already a schema for my xml file, based on the new teached and learned features I will try the latest version based on xml schema. I think the little bit more effort helps later to reuse my classes and methods in other projects better.

Comment: Hey @Shazter remember to mark an answer if it answered your question that way future readers will have a possible solution to their similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using `ToDictionary()` extension method. But performance wise, it is far better to use `Elements()` method rather than `Descendants()`; For further reading please read this blog post:
[WHY (OR WHEN) YOU SHOULD/SHOULDN’T USE DESCENDANTS() METHOD](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2013/08/why-or-when-you-shouldshouldnt-use-descendants-method.html)

And your query will look like this:

```
var customersDictionary = 
    xDoc.Root
        .Elements("cust")
        .ToDictionary(xe => 
                        xe.Attribute("Name").Value, xe => 
                        new Customers
                        {
                            DeviceID = (int)xe.Attribute("DeviceID"), 
                            Longitude = (int)xe.Attribute("Longitude"),  
                            Latitude = (int)xe.Attribute("Latitude"),
                            Device = (string)xe.Attribute("Device")
                        });
```

Comment: The link is very interessting and helpful.

Comment: @Shazter, please consider marking the most useful answer as an accepted answer in order to be useful for others too.